# what is 'datatodisplay' used for?

Tags: php, excel

I want to export my table to excel using this code :

```
<table id="ReportTable" width="781" border="2"> Or <div id id="ReportTable">
<tr>
<td><input type="hidden" id="datatodisplay" name="datatodisplay"></td>
<td><input class="bg" type="submit" value="Export To Excel"></td>
</tr></table></div>

<input type="hidden" id="datatodisplay" name="datatodisplay">
<input class="bg" type="submit" value="Export To Excel">
```

and itemexcel.php page :

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=itemcode.xls');
// Fix for crappy IE bug in download.
header("Pragma: ");
header("Cache-Control: ");
echo $_REQUEST['datatodisplay'];
?>
```

it can convert to excel but only the column header.
i want to know what is 'datatodisplay' used for and where i have to put that code ?
i put it just after table

thanks

Comment: Your question is not about Excel. The first code snippet is HTML, the second one is PHP. I added PHP tags.

Answer (score 0):

The value of the `datatodisplay` GET or POST variable is used as the content of the downloaded file. There's nothing visible in your code which populates that input, though, so as written it would generate an empty file.

Presumably there's supposed to be some Javascript which puts data into that hidden input? Generating an Excel file in Javascript would be complicated and messy, though...